# Is this python36 version issue? How to resolve it?

Tags: python-requests, python-3.6

I am on RHEL. I Installed python by following https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-python-3-6-4-on-centos-7/. I am getting an error when trying to install requests-kerberos

```
pip3 install requests-kerberos
```

returns

```
src/kerberos.c:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

sudo yum install gcc

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager 
Package gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version 
Nothing to do
```

Then I tried

```
sudo yum install python3-devel
```

and got

```
  Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
No package python3-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Then I tried

```
sudo yum install python36-devel
```

and got

```
    Error: Package: python36-devel-3.6.8-2.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: python36 = 3.6.8-2.el7.ius
           Installed: python3-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
               python36 = 3.6.8-10.el7
           Available: python36-3.6.8-2.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
               python36 = 3.6.8-2.el7.ius
Error: Package: python36-devel-3.6.8-2.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-2.el7.ius
           Installed: python3-libs-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-10.el7
           Available: python36-libs-3.6.8-2.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-2.el7.ius
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on RHEL, yet you follow a random Centos blog post. Below is a summary of some suggestions for a better python36 on both Centos and RHEL (6 or 7) from [Red Hat Developers Blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/):

1. **Enable [SCL](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/?search=python&policy=&repo=&order_by=-create_date&per_page=10)**

   Software Collections are RedHat Satellite repositories that also work if your servers are air-gapped i.e. have no internet.

   On Centos:

   yum install centos-release-scl

   On RHEL7

   yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
2. **Install the main SCL package:**

   yum install rh-python36
3. **Start using the Software Collection you just installed:**

   scl enable rh-python36 bash
4. **Upgrade pip3 with itself, and update setuptools:**

   pip3 install --upgrade pip

   pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
5. **Install requests-kerberos:**

   pip3 install requests-kerberos

**Notes**:

- 3. is equivalent to bash sourcing the file `/opt/rh/rh-python36/enable`
- 2. installing the main packages is sufficient by having these:

[image: rh-python36 dependencies (libs, headers, pip, setuptools)]

Comment: Is there rh-python36 available for Ubuntu? 'rh' means RedHat, right?

Comment: rh- is Red Hat indeed, not for Ubuntu.